# Get data after start date laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using the following query to get records that exist between `start date` and `end date`:

```
$event =Event::whereBetween('date', [
        $request->start_date, $request->end_date
    ])->orderBy('date', 'desc')->paginate(5);
```

This is working when I provide the start date and end date but, when I provide only the start date, then I didn't get any record – but I want records that exist after the start date if the end date is kept blank.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two alternatives from @babak-asharfi's answer

Using [`when()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses)

```php
$event = Event::when($request->end_date, 
    function($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereBetween('date', $request->start_date, $request->end_date);
    },
    function($query) use ($request){ 
        $query->where('date', '=>', $request->start_date);
    }
)->orderBy('date', 'desc')->paginate(5);
```

Or simply use a fallback date

```php
$event = Event::whereBetween('date', [
        $request->start_date, $request->end_date ?: '2999-12-31'
    ])->orderBy('date', 'desc')->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Laravel provides [Conditional Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses) for this use case

```php
$events = Event::query()
    ->when(
        $request->has('start_date') && $request->has('end_date'), 
        function($query, $request) {
            return $query->whereBetween('date', [
                $request->start_date, $request->end_date
            ]);
        }, 
        function($query, $request) {
            return $query->where('date', ' >=', $request->start_date);
        }
    )
    ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
    ->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
$query = Event::query();
            if ($request->has('start_date')){
               $query->whereBetween('date', [
                   $request->start_date, $request->end_date
               ]) 
            }else{
                $query->where('date', '>=', $request->start_date) 
            }
            $query->orderBy('date', 'desc')->paginate(5);
```